# RevTex with LaTex+bibTex references using hyperref cannot linebreak long text

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, line-breaking, revtex

I am using `RevTex` on a TeX Live distribution. After a long search on the internet, I've tried many solutions related to long url, but unsuccessfully, to linebreak the lengthy texts with `LaTex`+`bibTex`. My TeX Live was newly installed from the official website just a few days ago, hence it's not about outdated packages or so. Can anyone help to remedy this? Thanks!

**Update:** `pdfLaTex`doesn't has this problem as in the answer below pointed out. But I really wonder how to fix this within `LaTex`...

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{breakcites}
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
%\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This haha\cite{Rajaraman,EEMF2} was my favorite haha decades ago\cite{Skyrme}. But it doesn't work anymore.

%\RaggedRight
%\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax
\bibliography{reference.bib} 
\end{document}
```

My `bib` file is like this.

```
@article{Skyrme,
title = "A unified field theory of mesons and baryons ",
journal = "Nuclear Physics ",
volume = "31",
number = "",
pages = "556 - 569",
year = "1962",
note = "",
issn = "0029-5582",
doi = "10.1016/0029-5582(62)90775-7",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0029558262907757",
author = "T.H.R. Skyrme"
}

@article {EEMF2,
author = {Nagaosa, N. and Yu, X. Z. and Tokura, Y.},
title = {Gauge fields in real and momentum spaces in magnets: monopoles and skyrmions},
volume = {370},
number = {1981},
pages = {5806--5819},
year = {2012},
month = {Nov.},
doi = {10.1098/rsta.2011.0405},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2011.0405},
publisher = {The Royal Society},
issn = {1364-503X},
journal = {Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences}
}

@BOOK{Rajaraman,
title={Solitons and Instantons, Volume 15: An Introduction to Solitons and Instantons in Quantum Field Theory (North-Holland Personal Library)},
author={R. Rajaraman},
publisher={North Holland},
year={1987},
month={4},
edition={1},
isbn={9780444870476},
url={http://amazon.com/o/ASIN/0444870474/},
price={$72.95},
totalpages={418},
timestamp={2015.08.19},
}
```

And I get something like this.
[image]

The `log` file is the following.

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX) (preloaded format=latex 2016.8.14) 20 AUG 2016 12:55
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./SkXpaperMR.tex
(./SkXpaperMR.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-1.cls
Document Class: revtex4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revt
ex4/ for documentation)
Copyright (c) 2009 The American Physical Society.
mailto:revtex@aps.org
Licensed under the LPPL:
http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/base/lppl.txt
Arthur Ogawa <arthur_ogawa at sbcglobal dot net>
Based on work by David Carlisle <david at dcarlisle.demon.co.uk>.
ltxutil[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r utilities package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \@centercr on input line 308.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX eqnarray on input line 358.
\eqncolsep=\skip41
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing hyperref-unfriendly LaTeX definition of \mpfoot
note on input line 433.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LateX \@sect on input line 755.
\intertabularlinepenalty=\count79
\@tbpen=\count80
\@arstrutbox@hline=\box26
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing broken LaTeX \@xbitor on input line 1786.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Making \typeout \long on input line 2046.
ltxfront[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r frontmatter package (AO,DPC)]
\c@affil=\count81
\c@collab=\count82
\absbox=\box27
ltxgrid[2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r page grid package (portions licensed from W. E
. Baxter web at superscript.com)]
\c@linecount=\count83
\output@latex=\toks14
\box@size@1=\box28
\box@size@2=\box29
\@protection@box=\box30
\@topmark@saved=\toks15
\footins@saved=\box31
\footins@recovered=\box32
\column@recovered=\box33
\pagesofar=\box34
\footsofar=\box35
\pagegrid@col=\count84
Class revtex4-1 Info: Overriding \@vspace, \@vspacer, \@no@pgbk, \@newline, and
\\ on input line 5578.
\c@part=\count85
\c@section=\count86
\c@subsection=\count87
\c@subsubsection=\count88
\c@paragraph=\count89
\c@subparagraph=\count90
\abovecaptionskip=\skip42
\belowcaptionskip=\skip43
\c@figure=\count91
\fbox@1=\box36
\c@table=\count92
\fbox@2=\box37
\c@video=\count93
\fbox@4=\box38
\@bibdataout=\write3
\widetext@top=\box39
\widetext@bot=\box40
Class revtex4-1 Info: Selecting society aps on input line 7542.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps4-1.rtx
File: aps4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for docu
mentation)
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX society APS selected on input line 31.
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Selecting journal prb on input line 7544.
Class revtex4-1 Info: APS journal PRB selected on input line 7545.
Class revtex4-1 Warning: No type size specified, using default 10.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/aps10pt4-1.rtx
File: aps10pt4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
documentation)
Class revtex4-1 Info: RevTeX pointsize 10pt selected on input line 30.
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip44
\bibsep=\skip45
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count94
)
Class revtex4-1 Info: Repairing natbib's \BibitemShut on input line 7549.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/revtex/revsymb4-1.sty
Package: revsymb4-1 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ f
or documentation)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \REV@mathfrak on input line 119.
))
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds) That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds) that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds) In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode is ignored in DVI mode.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen102
\Hy@linkcounter=\count95
\Hy@pagecounter=\count96
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count97
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4486.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4491.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4494.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4501.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4506.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4735.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \href on input line 4999.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count98
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5088.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen103
\Fld@menulength=\count99
\Field@Width=\dimen104
\Fld@charsize=\dimen105
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6342.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6350.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6357.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6367.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6372.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6412.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6416.
\Hy@abspage=\count100
\c@Item=\count101
\c@Hfootnote=\count102
)
Package hyperref Message: Driver (default): hdvips.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
File: hdvips.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for dvips
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks17
\pdf@box=\box41
\pdf@toks=\toks18
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks19
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count103
\Fld@listcount=\count104
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count105
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
82.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip46
))
Class revtex4-1 Info: Patching LaTeX tabular. on input line 19.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Robustifying \LaTeX's \boldmath command on input line 19.
Class revtex4-1 Info: cite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 19.
Class revtex4-1 Info: mcite was not loaded (OK!) on input line 19.
Class revtex4-1 Info: multicol was not loaded (OK!) on input line 19.
(./SkXpaperMR.aux)
\openout1 = `SkXpaperMR.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 19.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box42
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 19.
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count106
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 19.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 19.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 19.
(./SkXpaperMR.out) (./SkXpaperMR.out)
\@outlinefile=\write4
\openout4 = `SkXpaperMR.out'.
Class revtex4-1 Info: Taking \maketitle back from hyperref on input line 19.
\openout3 = `SkXpaperMRNotes.bib'.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <7> on input line 22.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <5> on input line 22.
(./SkXpaperMR.bbl
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <9> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info: External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font) <6> on input line 9.
Overfull \hbox (399.09431pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 56--62
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 R. Ra-jara-man, [][][][],
[]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 66--71
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 N. Na-gaosa, X. Z. Yu, and Y. Tokura,
[]
Overfull \hbox (289.13164pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 66--71
[][][][]\OT1/cmr/m/n/9 .
[]
) [1]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 29.
(./SkXpaperMR.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 29.
*File List*
revtex4-1.cls 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
documentation)
aps4-1.rtx
aps10pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty 2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
url.sty 2013/09/16 ver 3.4 Verb mode for urls, etc.
natbib.sty 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-1.sty 2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for
documentation)
hyperref.sty 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
hobsub.sty 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
ifvtex.sty 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
intcalc.sty 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
ifpdf.sty 2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty 2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
bitset.sty 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
hopatch.sty 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
hycolor.sty 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
keyval.sty 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
ifxetex.sty 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
auxhook.sty 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
pd1enc.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg 2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
hdvips.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for dvips
pdfmark.def 2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
rerunfilecheck.sty 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
nameref.sty 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
SkXpaperMR.out
SkXpaperMR.out
SkXpaperMR.bbl
***********
Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 29.
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `SkXpaperMR.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck) Checksum: 7DA09F38BEEF7A06DED32AA86AC52B10;94.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
6168 strings out of 493014
88745 string characters out of 6137019
186926 words of memory out of 5000000
9714 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
6116 words of font info for 22 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
29i,5n,30p,194b,326s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
Output written on SkXpaperMR.dvi (1 page, 5340 bytes).
```

Answer (score 2):

With an current MiKTeX 2.9 I can compile your given code without errors or problems.

With the following MWE (I only used package `filecontents` to have bib file and TeX code concatenated to one compilable MWE):

```
\listfiles
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Skyrme,
title = "A unified field theory of mesons and baryons ",
journal = "Nuclear Physics ",
volume = "31",
number = "",
pages = "556 - 569",
year = "1962",
note = "",
issn = "0029-5582",
doi = "10.1016/0029-5582(62)90775-7",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0029558262907757",
author = "T.H.R. Skyrme"
}

@article {EEMF2,
author = {Nagaosa, N. and Yu, X. Z. and Tokura, Y.},
title = {Gauge fields in real and momentum spaces in magnets: monopoles and skyrmions},
volume = {370},
number = {1981},
pages = {5806--5819},
year = {2012},
month = {Nov.},
doi = {10.1098/rsta.2011.0405},
url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsta.2011.0405},
publisher = {The Royal Society},
issn = {1364-503X},
journal = {Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences}
}

@BOOK{Rajaraman,
title={Solitons and Instantons, Volume 15: An Introduction to Solitons and Instantons in Quantum Field Theory (North-Holland Personal Library)},
author={R. Rajaraman},
publisher={North Holland},
year={1987},
month={4},
edition={1},
isbn={9780444870476},
url={http://amazon.com/o/ASIN/0444870474/},
price={$72.95},
totalpages={418},
timestamp={2015.08.19},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,groupedaddress]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{breakcites}
%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}
%\urlstyle{same}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
This haha\cite{Rajaraman,EEMF2} was my favorite haha decades ago\cite{Skyrme}. But it doesn't work anymore.

%\RaggedRight
%\Urlmuskip=0mu plus 1mu\relax
\bibliography{\jobname} % <==================================== no .bib! 
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Please see, that command `\bibliography{references}`  needs no extension `.bib` as you wrote.  My `\jobname` is changed to the name of the TeX file containing the MWE.

My list of files is:

```
 *File List*
filecontents.sty    2011/10/08 v1.3 Create an external file from within a LaTeX document
revtex4-1.cls    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
  aps4-1.rtx
aps10pt4-1.rtx
textcase.sty    2004/10/07 v0.07 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  natbib.sty    2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
revsymb4-1.sty    2010/07/25/20:33:00 4.1r (http://publish.aps.org/revtex4/ for documentation)
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
 hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
 ***********
```

For example see, that my package `hyperref` is from 2016, yours is from  2012.  That is very old, please update your TeX distribution.

**Update:**

I compiled this code with `pdflatex` to get an result without error.  It seems you used `latex` over `dvi` to `pdf`, then I get the same bad layout you have.

**Conclusion**  Please compile your code with `pdflatex mwe.tex` in the case file `mwe.tex` contains your main file of TeX code ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it's weird...I installed from the official Texlive early this year. And you see it's texlive 2015 in the beginning of my log file. Any idea why or how to make sure of a latest version?

Comment: Sorry. Maybe it's not the case. See my updated log file which is from another Texlive installed a few days ago on another pc. Now the hyperref appears to be 2016, but still no linebreak...

Comment: En...Thank you all the same. Actually I am aware of that workaround. I was trying to avoid pdflatex for some reason. Maybe I should have said it more clearly in my question. Apology.